# Azure Blob Storage - listblobs in $logs container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have a azure blob storage, with logging enabled.
I can view these logs and download the blobs using the Management Portal.
But now I'm trying to list those logs using the Client api.
Something along the lines:

```
let account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true)
let client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient()
let container = client.GetContainerReference "$logs"
container.ListBlobs()
```

But this throws a web exception code `400 Bad Request`.
I can. however, list blobs from other containers on this client.
I understand I need to be authenticated for this container, but I'm using the primary access key for the credentials.
So why can't I get the $logs blobs?

Thanks

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me. Can you tell me what version of storage client library are you using? I used both 1.8 and 2.0 and it worked in both cases.

Comment: on my machine it's 1.7.0... um.. where to update? :)

Comment: You can either download the latest SDK from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/ or reference latest storage client libraries from Nuget: http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/. HTH.

Comment: Oh well, I was using depreceated StorageClient, now I'm using the up to date dlls. Now listblobs returns only one item: ``https://{storage}.blob.core.windows.net/$logs/blob/`` though there a lot more blobs in the container...

Comment: changing this to answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments above, you would need to use the latest version of storage client library which you can get from Nuget: http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/.

Here's the sample code:

```
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let credentials = new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey")
    System.Console.WriteLine(credentials.AccountName)
    let account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true)
    System.Console.WriteLine(account.BlobEndpoint)
    let client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    let container = client.GetContainerReference "$logs"
    System.Console.WriteLine(container.Uri)
    let blobs = container.ListBlobs("", true, BlobListingDetails.All, null, null);
    for blob in blobs do
        System.Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri)
    let response = System.Console.ReadLine()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Above code needs Storage Client Library 2.0.

The reason you're getting back only one item is because you're calling `ListBlobs` function with no parameters. If you look at the definition for this function here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx), you'll see that you can get all blobs in a blob container by specifying `useFlatBlobListing` parameter to true (which I did in the code above). Do give it a try, it would return a list of all blobs in your blob container.

Comment: Thank you very much :) In the end I set useFlatBlobListing to false and wondered why this had no effect...

Comment: I'm just too curious what language is that? :)